# zero value where there shouldn't be

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

i am racking my brain to figure out the simplest thing. With the code below, i am getting zero values.
When a user fills in something in a combobox called "cbocolor" and then switches to the next textbox my system does a vlookup.
If the entry in "cbocolor" exists on my contact page, but column 2 has nothing, i want it to just come back with nothing ("") as my answer....but it always comes back zero.
Please, andy help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
If cbocolor.value <> "" Then

    TextBox1.value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cbocolor.value, _
       Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False), "Enter New Info")

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is attemptng to return an empty cell which results in a **0** (i.e. *zero*) being displayed. Append a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) to avoid this.

```
TextBox1.value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cbocolor.value, _
   Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False)&"", "Enter New Info")
```

I don't believe you can use `WorksheetFunction.IfError` in that fashion. If you run into trouble consider,

```
if IsError(application.Match(cbocolor.value, Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts").Columns(1), 0)) Then
    TextBox1.value = "Enter New Info"
else
    TextBox1.value = Application.VLookup(cbocolor.value, Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False) & ""
end if
```

Error handling is different within VBA and the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) does not catch an error thrown from a worksheet no-match the way that a worksheet formula does.

Comment: I'm a little concerned with your use of the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). Please see above for possible alternative.

Comment: ya its not working, wondering what you think, and thanks again for your help. Before i added your - & " " - if it didnt find a match it worked, but gave a zero value, if it found the cbocolor in my range it gave the vlookup answer. Now when i added your edit, if it finds an asnwer to the vlookup it does not give a zero value (GREAT) but if it does not find something in the range to vlookup then i get an error. So it is as if the two methods (mine vs yours) are the exact opposite

Comment: also, not sure if i am allowed to say this on this site...i dont really know how it works, but can i hire people on this site (like yourself) to assist me in larger problems?

Comment: ① What is the address (i.e. **RefersTo**) of the `Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts")` range? I need to fully reproduce the situation so I can test all three possibles (match, match but return blank, no match). ② There is a new beta program at http://stackoverflow.com/jobs but I have yet to submit a Cv for it (will soon), You can try there for very competent help or reach me at the address displayed on my [Microsoft Answers Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590) profile page.

Comment: so sorry i took a while (holidays) next comment has the code

Comment: If cbocolor.Value <> "" Then
TextBox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cbocolor.Value, Worksheets("CONTACTS").Range("allcontacts"), 2, False), "")

Comment: so a person enters their name in cbocolor, then the click into textbox1, where they would enter their phone number, but i have the system do a vlookup to see if the phone number exsists already. if it does it should pop up, if the name entered in cbocolor does not exist (new contact) then when they click into textbox1 i just want it blank, whereas as  i explained, my code enters a zero if the person exists BUT has no telephone number yet. Is that as clear as i hope it sounds :) thanks